# Возвращение результата метода

Tags: java

При выполнении различных заданий сталкивался с одним вопросом, который до сих пор не могу понять.
Пусть есть метод, позволяющий находить произведение какого-то поля на число "a" (к примеру поле chislo):

```
public void proizvedenie(int a){
    chislo = chislo * a;
}
```

И тот же метод:

```
public int proizvedenie(int a){
    int proiz = chislo * a;
    return proiz;
}
```

В итоге я получу один и тот же результат. В первом случае метод не возвращает никакого значения в отличии от целого значения во втором случае, но ведь, если я буду использовать первый метод, получу тот же результат, что и при использовании второго. Что означает "не возвращает никакого значения" и какая тогда разница между двумя случаями, только в структуре?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В этом методе

```
public void proizvedenie(int a){
chislo = chislo * a;
}
```

изменяется член класса `chislo`. То есть после выполнения метода значение члена класса `chislo` изменится.

Данный метод

```
public int proizvedenie(int a){
int proiz = chislo * a;
return proiz;
}
```

не меняет значение члена класса  `chislo`. После выполнение этого метода значение члена класса `chislo` будет таким же, как до вызова метода. Этот метод устанавливает лишь значение локальной переменной `proiz`, значение которой возвращается из функции.

Так что эти два метода не эквивалентны.

Вы могли бы написать метод следующим образом

```
public int proizvedenie(int a){
    return chislo = chislo * a;
}
```

В этом случае не только изменяется значение члена класса `chislo`, но и возвращается его новое значение. Такой подход удобен, когда вызов метода желательно связывать в цепочку с другими вызовами методов или функций, как, например, вывода нового значения на консоль.

Другой подход - это вернуть предыдущее значение члена данных

```
public int proizvedenie(int a){
    int old_value = chislo;
    chislo = chislo * a;
    return old_value;
}
```

Но в любом случае значение члена класса `chislo` в обоих методах изменяется.

Comment: Ну вот( Опоздал секунд на 15 и лишился 20 репы(

Comment: Понял. А как понять когда лучше какой тип значения присваивать результату функции?

Comment: @MuscledBoy Например, если это поле каких-нибудь флагов, то лучше возвращать предыдущее значение, чтобы, например, его затем можно было бы восстановить после временного изменения. Если метод не только меняет значение члена класса но и вычисляет какой-нибудь результат, то лучше этот результат возвращать, если он сам по себе представляет ценность. А так, обычно, пишутся отдельно геттеры и сеттеры.

Comment: Огромное спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Разница этих двух методов в следующем:

1. В первом методе вы изменяете значение поля `chislo` экземпляра класса и которого вызывали этот метод.
2. Во втором случае вы не изменяете значение поля экземпляра класса, но получаете его произведения на аргумент и возвращаете его из метода.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ)